# Vue router, the page doesn't work after changing the path

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I've got the problem, whenever I change the path in vue.config.js and vue-router the page doesn't work on the local server in XAMMP. I've changed the publicPath and outputPath.

More details here, I put this link because nobody has responded.
In the link below there's also a link to the repository on GitHub:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/problem-with-vue-routing-on-vue-cli-3-content-doesnt-show-in-the-different-path/55000

Thank you for any help. I got badly stacked here.

Comment: While using vue-router you also need to set router base property in router's index file.Have you done that??const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: /foldername
})

Comment: So if I have publicPath chosen to be /ninja-custom/app/

Comment: I have to put base: /   or base: /ninja-custom/app/

Comment: Set as base:/ninja-custom/app and don't forget to build again to check the results.

Comment: It helped, thank you very much!

Comment: @Riddhi, please, post your comment as an answer and OP will accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using vue-router you also need to set router base property in router's index file.
Have you done that??
const router = new Router({ mode: 'history', base: /foldername })
Refer the following link for more details:
https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base